# Who can read the "Wehrpass" (Military identity card) of my grandpa?

Tags: handwriting

Good day,

Unfortunately, I cannot read all of the entries of my grandpa's "Wehrpass".

Please have a look, I tried my very best and marked everything unclear with '**???**'

[image]

**Left page:**

- 11.05.1940: **???** in Holland 9./**???**
- 13.05.1940: **???** in Belgien 9./**???**
- 10.10.1939 bis 10.05.1940: Verwendung im Operationsgebiet der Westfront
- 10.05.1940 bis 04.06.1940: "Der Durchbruch zum Ärmelkanal", "Die Schlacht in Flandern in **???**"
- 05.06.1940 - 25.06.1940: **???** in Frankreich
- 26.06.1940: Einsatz im besetzten Gebiet, **???**
- 30.03.1941: **???** Stützung der Luftwaffe im Kampf gegen England
- 31.03.1941 - 21.06.1941: Einsatz im Generalgouvernement
- 22.06.1941 - 03.07.1941: Doppelschlacht **???** **???**
- 03.07.1941 - 10.07.1941: **???** bis zum **???**
- 10.07.1941 - 15.07.1941: **???** **???** **???** befestigt **???**

**Right Page**

- 16.07.1941 - 05.08.1941: Luftschlacht von **???**
- 12.08.1941 - 19.08.1941: Schlacht bei **???** in **???**
- 02.10.1941 - 14.10.1941: **???**schlacht **???** **???** in Schlacht **???** **???**
- 08.10.1941 - 15.11.1941: Kämpfe im **???** Moskau's Ringstellung
- 16.11.1941 - 20.03.1942: Einsatz im Heimatkriegsgebiet
- 21.03.1942 - 17.05.1942: Einsatz im Generalgouvernment
- 18.08.1942 - 18.11.9143: Einsatz im Operationsgebiet der Ostfront
- 19.11.1944 - 28.02.1944: Einsatz in Rumänien
- 01.03.1944 - 01.05.1944: Einsatz im Generalgouvernement im **???** der Luftflotte 4
- 02.05.1944 - 17.10.1944: Einsatz im Rahmen der Reichsverteidigung als Nachrichtensoldat im verbündeten Ausland (Ungarn) innerhalb des **???** **???** Reich
- 18.10.1944 - 03.10.1944: Verwendung im Heimatkriegsgebiet
- 31.10.1944 - 31.12.1944: Einsatz im Rahmen der Reichsverteidigung als Nachrichtensoldat im Prektorat Böhmen und Mähren

Comment: The first two lines look like Kurrent and I think its "fussmarsch i. Holland" and "fussmarsch i. Belgien"

Comment: 05.06.1940 - 25.06.1940: ??? in Frankreich is probably "Schlacht in Frankreich"

Comment: @InterestedPerson Has your question been answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Left Page

```
11.05.1940: Einmarsch in Holland 9./Ln. Rgt. 12 [Luftnachrichten-Regiment 12?]
13.05.1940: Einmarsch in Belgien 9./Ln. Rgt. 12
10.10.1939 bis 10.05.1940: Verwendung im Operationsgebiet der Westfront
10.05.1940 bis 04.06.1940: "Der Durchbruch zum Ärmelkanal
                           "Die Schlacht in Flandern u.[und] in Artois
05.06.1940 - 25.06.1940: Schlacht in Frankreich
26.06.1940 - 30.03.1941: Einsatz im besetzten Gebiet, Unter-
                         stützung der Luftw. im Kampf gegen Engl.
31.03.1941 - 21.06.1941: Einsatz im Generalgouvernement
22.06.1941 - 03.07.1941: Doppelschlacht Bialystok u. Minsk
03.07.1941 - 10.07.1941: Verfolgungskämpfe über Beresina bis zum Dnjepr
10.07.1941 - 15.07.1941: Durchbruch durch die befestigte Dnjeprlinie
```

Right Page

```
16.07.1941 - 05.08.1941: Umfassungsschlacht von Smolensk
12.08.1941 - 19.08.1941: Schlacht bei Rogatschew u. Gomel
02.10.1941 - 14.10.1941: Durchbruchsschlacht ostw. [ostwärts]
                         Smolensk u. Schlacht um Wjasma
08.10.1941 - 15.11.1941: Kämpfe um die Moskauer Ringstellung
16.11.1941 - 20.03.1942: Einsatz im Heimatkriegsgebiet
21.03.1942 - 17.05.1942: Einsatz im Generalgouvernment
18.08.1942 - 18.11.9143: Einsatz im Operationsgebiet 
                         der Ostfront
19.11.1944 - 28.02.1944: Einsatz in Rumänien
01.03.1944 - 01.05.1944: Einsatz im Generalgouvernement im 
                         Bereich der Luftflotte 4
02.05.1944 - 17.10.1944: Einsatz im Rahmen der Reichsverteidigung
                         als Nachrichtensoldat im verbündeten Ausland 
                         (Ungarn) innerhalb des Lfl. Kdos. Reich
                         [Luftflotten-Kommandos Reich]
18.10.1944 - 03.10.1944: Verwendung im Heimatkriegsgebiet
31.10.1944 - 31.12.1944: Einsatz im Rahmen der Reichsverteidigung als
                         Nachrichtensoldat im Protektorat Böhmen und Mähren
```

Comment: Ein paar Kleinigkeiten: Linksseite wohl "B**e**resina" statt "Baresina"; Rechtsseite "Durchbruchsschlacht **ostw.** (ostwärts) Smolensk". "Ostwärts" hier in Präpositionalverwendung, diese ist zumal in den Schlachtplänen selbst belegt, siehe [hier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelschlacht_bei_Wjasma_und_Brjansk#Hintergrund) letzter Absatz.

Comment: @marquinho: Prima, ich hab es eingefügt.

Comment: Die Angaben vom 31.3.41 bis zum 17.5.42 wurden von derselben Person geschrieben. Nach Vergleich aller Einträge lese ich statt *Be[la]gerungsschlacht[?]*  daher *??fa?ungsschlacht*. Der erste Buchstabe ist sicher kein "B"; vgl. *Beresina*. Es könnte vielleicht *Umfassungsschlacht* heißen - ein Synonym für Kesselschlacht. Vgl. https://de.linkfang.org/wiki/Kesselschlacht_bei_Smolensk Würde auch vom Zeitraum passen.

Comment: Stimmt, "Umfassungsschlacht" passt inhaltlich perfekt und kann man da rauslesen.

Comment: Thank you (all) very much. It means a lot to me that you helped my family and me in that case. And I think it was quite difficult to read, so many thanks!